# How to navigate between UITextFields in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView with UITextFields in cells, and in Sections.

I also have a toolbar with "Next" and "Previous" buttons.

The TextFields don't have the same distance between them.

I would like to know what is the best approach to take in order to navigate between them.
Possibly using becomeFirstResponder?

i.e:

[image]

**RED** represent the **static** UITextFields which are subviews of a view.

**BLUE** represent the **dynamic** UITextFields which are subviews of a cell.

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate between them"?

Comment: You should create an NSMutableArray holding all the text fields in the order they are on the scree. When prev/next tapped, find the current first responder in the array and move to the prev/next if one exists. Also this way you can enable/disable the prev/next buttons when any of your text field becomes the first responder. You can keep the array up to date as you know when the user adds a new field and then you also know the position of the new text field in the array.

Comment: Szabi Thank you for the reply! Thats kinda what I did, however, I was unable to move to some TextFields since they were in a cell that didn't existed yet. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had meet the same question in my project a few months ago. You could have a try by my solution:

when your  Next/Previous button clicked, let tableView select the right indexPath you want(Pay attention to the first cell, last cell and the cell between sections; disable/enable button if need).

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: rightIndexPath.row inSection:rightIndexPath.section] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

override two methods in cell.m

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if (selected) {
        [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

PS: In my project, the next/pre buttons are set in textField's inputAccessoryView. So i pass the click action from cell to viewController by my custom delegate.